# How to allocate memory to a struct in a function?

Tags: c

I have a function `create_system` in this function I want to allocate memory to an array called `c_array` that its type is a pointer to a struct Activity.
I get that the way I tried to allocate the memory is wrong ! I tried everything and here is what I got after searching all over google to this way to allocate:

> `Activity* ((*sys)->c_array)=malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity));`

but I get the following error:

> `expected ')' before '->' token`

Any idea of I is doing wrong here!

what i have tried :

```
typedef struct SRoomSystem
{
Activity *c_array;

} RoomSystem;
int num_challenges=6;//this is just an example
Result create_system(RoomSystem **sys){
   Activity* ((*sys)->c_array)=malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity));
}
```

Comment: `(*sys)->c_array=malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity)); OR
    (*sys)->c_array=(Activity*)malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity));`

Comment: thank you so much i think it worked !

Comment: @Steephen: Don't use unnecessary cqasts; they are potentially dangerous. Specifically never cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general to a pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this problem is most likely the thing that @Steephen has already pointed out: `(*sys)->c_array = malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity));`. It's most likely that the extra bracket was causing the error.

Comment: so there is no need for Activity* before (*sys)->c_array = malloc(num_challenges * sizeof(Activity)); :|

Comment: @lauren, Right. You are assigning to a variable (a member of a struct), not declaring one.

Comment: omg yess true !!! why i didn't think about this !! thank you so much :))